# column_spec does not render in beamer presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, beamer, kableextra

[image]

So as picture shows, after using kableExtra in beamer presentation my tables don't render properly.

My header included

```
 header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
```

Code to example:

```
StrukturaWiekuIPlciWedlugProgramu2 %>%
    mutate(Kobiety = cell_spec(Kobiety,"latex", 
           background =  ifelse(Kobiety > 0, "#91d400", "white")),
           `Mężczyźni` = cell_spec(`Mężczyźni`,   "latex",
           background =  ifelse(`Mężczyźni` > 0, "#91d400", "white")))   %>%
           kable(format = "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
           kableExtra::column_spec(4, bold = T) %>%
           kable_styling("striped", full_width = F, 
           position = "center",
           font_size = 7)
```

Comment: (1) Please make a reproducible minimal working example, as is we don't have your data. (2) Is that the literal indentation of your `header-includes:` portion of the yaml block? I've always had `header-` in column 1 and the bullets indented (I indent 4, but I don't know that 2 wouldn't work).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but loading `\usepackage{float}` with beamer does not make any sense, beamer does not have a floating mechanism. `\usepackage{xcolor}` is unnecessary, beamer already loads it. `tabu` should better be avoided, it is more or less broken and only held together with duck tape. Instead of loading the `colortbl` package one should better do `\documentclass[xcolor={table}]{beamer}` (to do this with rmarkdown there should be some options to pass arguments to the documentclass)